# Angular ContentChild is always undefined using injection token

Tags: angular, angular14, angular-content-projection

I'm trying to implement a bridge pattern for content projection. In the component that has the `ng-content` tag in the HTML, I tried to get it via this line, where `BUTTON_ENABLED_DIALOG` is an `InjectionToken`:

```js
@ContentChild(BUTTON_ENABLED_DIALOG, {static: true}) content?: IButtonEnabledDialog
```

The calling component does add `BUTTON_ENABLED_DIALOG` to the providers array.

That value is never getting set, even though I see the content.  A tiny StackBlitz example can be found at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pgnuny?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong usage of `@ContentChild` decorator here. It can be used in the upper level of projected element to get access to the projected content, - within the `AppComponent` in your example.

For your purpose you can just use the `Dependency Injection`:

```
export class ButtonEnabledDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(@Inject(BUTTON_ENABLED_DIALOG) private content: IButtonEnabledDialog
) {}
```

And get access to your injection token.